# How can I update my MySQL connection through spring to handle TLSv1.2?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a previously working Spring MVC project using Spring Boot, Spring JPA, Spring Data.  My DBA updated the security on the MySQL server to accept only TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 and now my website Spring MVC won't connect to it.  The website literally died the minute they put the TLS 1.2 on it, so it's my problem, with their security.

Please note that my dev box is entirely isolated.  I cannot copy and paste many lines of code and have to hand type it.

First, Tried to add the SSL via the JDBC string:

```
jdbc:mysql://host:3306/bdd_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

Second, Tried to add More information (per this example):

```
jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/MYDB?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:cert/keystore.jks&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=123456&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:cert/truststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=123456
```

Third, tried to add java security:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/keystore/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

Fourth, tried to add via Spring properties:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

After many attempts to get this resolved, I have a setup with 2 and 4 in place.  The jdbc connection property resolves and finds my key files and unlocks them, so the URL changes (2) does work.

So, after all this, I still get:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Caused by: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
```